# Understanding formal algebra problem: Deciding if set is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm self-studying algebra and found the following problem in my book:

> Decide if the following sets are vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ with the operations defined below:

> $i$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $v_1\circ v_2=v_1-v_2$ and the usual product.

> $ii$. $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual sum and $a \circ v=-av$.

etc.

The definition given in the book of a vector space over a field $K$ is a an *abelian group* $(V, +)$ with a group action $\cdot:K \times V\rightarrow V$ satisfying that $a\cdot(v+w)=av+wv,1\cdot v=v$ and $a\cdot (b \cdot v) =(a\cdot b) \cdot v$ .

I have two doubts with respect to the excercises.

$1$. I have not seen vector spaces $(V, +, \circ)$, this is vector spaces with two operations instead of simply the sum. Should I evaluate that $(V, +)$ and $(V, \circ)$ are both abelian groups? Or how does the definition given before of vector space translate to multiple operators? Same goes for $ii$: should I check that $a \circ v$ satisfies the group action properties stated above?

$2$. The problem seems to use operations not defined for the given groups. For example, case $ii$, $a \circ v$ is a group action resulting in $-a\cdot v$. However, this assumes the group action $\cdot$ between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined, which is not something stated in the problem.

I know I'm probably just terribly confused, and since I'm self-studying I have no-one to turn to for clarifications on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not too impressed by the confusing notation of the book you're using. I hope it improves as you go on.

Comment: @TedShifrin It is the main textbook of the linear algebra course in the faculty of Mathematics, University of Buenos Aires (I'm from Argentina). I'm glad it is not just me who finds it confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\circ$ stands respectively for a proposed addition to make $(V,\circ, \cdot)$ into a vector space in question one and in question two it is a proposed multiplication by scalar to make $(V,+,\circ)$ into a vector space.

Let me illustrate with another example. Take $V = \mathbb{R}$ with addition given by
$$a \circ b = 2(a+b)$$
and the usual scalar multiplication. I claim that $(V,\circ)$ is not an abelian group and hence that $(V,\circ,\cdot)$ is not a vector space. Notice that it fails associativity:
$$(a\circ b)\circ c = [2(a+b)]\circ c = 2(2(a+b)+c) = 4a +4b +2c.$$
$$a\circ(b\circ c) = a\circ[2(b+c)] = 2(a+2(b+c))=2a+4b+4c.$$

Comment: I see, I see. What confused me is the fact that defining $a \circ b = v_1 - v_2$, as in question $i$, implies some definition of the $-$ (or $+$) operator for the set, which was never given. You, on the contrary, have defined the group $(V, +, \circ)$ with the $+$ and inspected whether $(V, \circ)$ satisfies the properties of a vector space. Since $+$ has been defined in your case, $a \circ b = 2(a+b)$ is natural and doesn't cause the confusion $v_1 \circ v_2 = v_1 - v_2$ caused in my mind.

Comment: In general, when dealing with problems such as $i$, should I just assume every operator used is defined in the traditional terms ($+, \cdot, \text{etc}$)?

Comment: When you have questions like this it is usually safe to assume that the right hand side defines the left hand side, thus the right hand side must have everything defined to begin with e.g. in question i) "-" must be the 'usual' minus since nothing else is stated.

Comment: However, once you have some operation which does define a vector space the symbol for addition of vectors is almost always "$+$" instead of "$\circ$" and similarly for the multiplication by scalar.

Comment: Much appreciated!